# "Error downloading URL: " Using TDownloadUrl in a TThread.Execute

Tags: multithreading, delphi, download

I´m having a few problems trying to download a file with 14mb using a TThread.
When I put the download code into the TDataModule, the download is ok, but after a refactoring and move the code to TThread.Execute, on DownloadUrl.ExecuteTarget I receive the error message on the Title.

The code in the TThread:

```
procedure TThreadDownload.Execute;
var
    DownloadFile: TDownloadUrl;
begin
try
    DownloadFile := TDownLoadURL.Create(nil);
    DownloadFile.URL := 'http://.....';
    DownloadFile.Filename := 'c:\';
    DownloadFile.OnDownloadProgress := URL_OnDownloadProgress; //Procedure created to     update the progressbar.
    DownloadFile.ExecuteTarget(nil);
    DownloadFile.Free;
except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      MessageDlg('Error'+#13+#10+E.Message,
        mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
    end;
end;
```

end;

Any idea about what is wrong?

Thanks.

I solved the problem:

after read the code of DownloadUrl, I made little changes in the code, and now it´s working fine.

Code OK:

```
procedure TThreadDownload.AtualizarTela;
begin
    with _Form do
    begin
        TcxProgressBar(_Form.FindComponent(_ProgressBar.Name)).Properties.Max :=     _TotalDownload;
        TcxProgressBar(_Form.FindComponent(_ProgressBar.Name)).Position := _StatusDownload;
    end;
end;

constructor TThreadDownload.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; AForm: TFrmMyFormWithProgress; AProgress: TcxProgressBar; PathUrl, PathLocal: String);
begin
    inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
    _Form := AForm;
    _ProgressBar := AProgress;
    _PathUrl := PathUrl;
    _PathLocal := PathLocal;
    FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TThreadDownload.Execute;
var
    DownloadFile: TDownloadUrl;
begin
    try
        DownloadFile := TDownloadUrl.Create(nil);
        DownloadFile.URL := _PathUrl;
        DownloadFile.Filename := _PathLocal;
        DownloadFile.OnDownloadProgress := URL_OnDownloadProgress;
        DownloadFile.ExecuteTarget(_Form);
        DownloadFile.Free;
    except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
            MessageDlg('Error Message'+#13+#10+E.Message, mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure TThreadDownload.URL_OnDownloadProgress(Sender: TDownLoadURL; Progress,
ProgressMax: Cardinal; StatusCode: TURLDownloadStatus; StatusText: String;
  var Cancel: Boolean);
begin
    _TotalDownload := ProgressMax;
    _StatusDownload := Progress;
    Synchronize(AtualizarTela);
end;
```

Comment: I assume you `Synchronize` the VCL code in `URL_OnDownloadProgress`?

Comment: Yes, in the URL_OnDownloadProgress I set Variables with Max and Position and call Synchronize to update the progressbar on the form.

I see in the ExtActns unit, the ExecuteTarget use a Parent Control, i think that this is my problem, Is This?

Comment: `TDownloadURL.ExecuteTarget()` does not use a "Parent Control". Also, `TDownloadURL` does not use the `Target` parameter of `ExecuteTarget()` so you can set it to nil.  On a separate note, your thread has a direct pointer to the ProgressBar, you don't need to use `FindComponent()` to access it. And `MessageDlg()` is not thread-safe, so use `Windows.MessageBox()` instead.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use `TDownloadURL` in a thread, specifically because it is a `TAction` and actions are meant for use in the main thread.  I would use an actual HTTP client component/library instead, such as Indy's `TIdHTTP` component or the `WinInet`/`WinHTTP` API.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do it, because TDownloadUrl would not work properly. If you would create 2 or more objects base on TDownloadUrl class and make them download simultaneously they would not return results, each thread will remain frozen. Even if you will free the objects after this collision has happened (I freed them from main thread), it would take exactly 5 minutes for the system to resolve it, but even after all the objects will be freed all other will be created "harmed" (meaning they will freeze straight away).

[Here](https://yadi.sk/d/ZYIpZrLCaCUyV?ncrnd=4049) is my unit for Delphi-7 that may be used to reproduce this situation, if someone would like to check my statement.